# jquery selector.closest function

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a small classified ads script that has been developed in laravel with of course some jQuery functionalities. I just applied some changes on behalf of the design sturcture, however I have an issue with a script.

Old markup:

```
    @foreach($ads as $ad)
        <tr>
            <td width="100">
                <img src="{{ media_url($ad->feature_img) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <h5><a href="{{ route('single_ad', $ad->slug) }}" target="_blank">{{ $ad->title }}</a> ({!! $ad->status_context() !!})</h5>
                <p class="text-muted">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {!! $ad->full_address() !!} <br />  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ $ad->posting_datetime()  }}
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('edit_ad', $ad->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger deleteAds" data-slug="{{ $ad->slug }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

jQuery:

```
        $('.deleteAds').on('click', function(){
            if ( ! confirm('{{ trans('app.are_you_sure') }}')){
                return '';
            }
            var selector = $(this);
            var slug = selector.data('slug');
            $.ajax({
                url : '{{ route('delete_ads') }}',
                type: "POST",
                data: {slug:slug, _token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'},
                success : function (data) {
                    if (data.success == 1){
                        selector.closest('tr').hide('slow');
                        toastr.success(data.msg, '@lang('app.success')', toastr_options);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This function is being triggered once I decide to delete an item (one of my classifieds) and will than hide the related tr as well as generate a success message (toastr)

Now the new markup is a bit more extensive being:

```
    @foreach($ads as $ad)
    <!-- ad-item -->
    <div class="ad-item row">
        <div class="item-image-box col-sm-4">
            <div class="item-image">
                <a href="{{ route('single_ad', $ad->slug) }}"><img src="{{ media_url($ad->feature_img) }}" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-info col-sm-8">
            <div class="ad-info">
                <h3 class="item-price">$800.00</h3>
                <h4 class="item-title"><a href="{{ route('single_ad', $ad->slug) }}">{{ $ad->title }} / ({!! $ad->status_context() !!})</a></h4>
                <div class="item-cat">
                    <span><a href="#">Electronics &amp; Gedgets</a></span> /
                    <span><a href="#">Tv &amp; Video</a></span>
                </div>                                      
            </div>
            <div class="ad-meta">
                <div class="meta-content">
                    <span class="dated">Posted On: <a href="#">{{ $ad->posting_datetime() }}</a></span>
                    <span class="visitors">Visitors: 221</span> 
                </div>                                      
                <div class="user-option pull-right">
                    <a class="edit-item" href="{{ route('edit_ad', $ad->id) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a class="deleteAds delete-item" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ad-item -->
    @endforeach
```

I've tried to change the jQuery part of **selector.closest('tr').hide('slow');** to become **selector.closest('ad-item').hide('slow');** however it does not seem to work or do the job.

Any ideas how I can tweak the related jQuery part to have this function work again? Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `selector.closest('ad-item')`  is looking for an element of type `ad-item` BUT its a class...  `selector.closest('.ad-item')`

Comment: Thank you for your response - I've tried that earlier with various combinations such as .ad-item or .ad-item row or .ad-item.row , neither worked.

Comment: I have no idea how do you test/debug it but if `selector` refers to `.deleteAds` then `selector.closest('.ad-item')` will match expected row. If not, then you didn't provided all relevant code or you are doing something else wrong... It could be just that you don't bind click event correctly or didn't clear cache or...?!

Comment: Managed to get it to work by adding a div id and changing the selector to #idname , for some reason it did not work with .ad-item

Comment: Following your code, `selector` seems to refer to your clicked `.deleteAds` which means, as A. Wolff mentioned your code should match the item you want to. When using an id, I hope you make sure it is **unique** in your dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the `.add-item` is not in your markup the click event might not be bound correctly on page load. In addition, jQuery needs to prevent the default behaviour of the `<a>`-tag in your markup.

Consider a div, wrapping all your `.add-item`'s, this code should work:

```
<div class="item-list">
@foreach($ads as $ad)
    <!-- ad-item -->
    <div class="ad-item row">
        ....
        ...
        <div class="item-info col-sm-8">
            <div class="ad-meta">
                ...                                   
                <div class="user-option pull-right">
                    <a class="deleteAds delete-item" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ad-item -->
@endforeach
</div>
```

Following makes sure your `click event` will work on `.deleteAdds` that are not present in the dom on page load:

```
$('.item-list').on('click', '.deleteAds', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selector = $(this);
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success : function (data) {
            console.log('while this works, your code below should too.');
            if (data.success == 1){
                selector.closest('.add-item').hide('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```